# Jquery.get() on a cshtml page and post a .CS file

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

We have a cshtml (`Example.cshtml`) page inside an ASP.NET MVC 4.0 project (which gets invoked by a controller).

On click of a button (`SendData`) on `Example.cshtml`, the cshtml page posts the data in the form of a query string.

This data should be picked up by jQuery.get() and after couple of processing steps the processed data should be sent back to a .CS file

My question is: how do I retrieve the data from the query string using `$.get()`?
Once the data is retrieved by `jQuery.Get()`, how do I proceed after that, how do I send data back to .cs file ?

Below is the `.get()` usage:

```
     $('#CSSIdentifierforSenData').click(function() {
         $.ajax({
             url: sitePath +"Example.cshtml",
             type: 'GET',
             data: 'somedata',      // how to retrieve from query string?
             success:function(data) {
               //  
             } 
         });
     });    // End Click
```

Comment: You appear to have some misunderstandings about how ajax works. The return data won't have any query string, that's for posting data. Please review the jQuery docs and dome some research about AJAX.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This person tried to word their question as best they could. If you are downvoting it, please say why so everyone can learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing isn't standard ASP.NET MVC.

You should be requesting the file contents from the Controller which sends back the view.  For example:

```
public class ExampleController : Controller 
{  
        public ActionResult Example() 
        { 
            return View();
        } 
}
```

The `View` here will refer to `Example.cshtml`

In your AJAX call you should be requesting it like:

```
   $('#CSSIdentifierforSenData').click(function() {
         $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("Example")',
             type: 'GET',
             success:function(data) {
               //  
             } 
         });
     });
```

The data you're trying to get from the `AJAX` request should be handled in the `Controller` layer (Which I've added in for you).  You could use a service class to retrieve the data you need and pass it to the View via a strongly typed `ViewModel`.

On the `AJAX` success function you can access the `Example.cshtml` contents which is held in the `data` variable.
You could then fade this into a section of the page for example using `jQuery`.

To `POST` data you could use a `FORM` or the jQuery `AJAX` method again, but use `POST` rather than `GET` and pass the data you want up to the server.  Again you should be using a Controller to handle this interaction.